# Independent and parallel work of clients with the server

Tags: winapi, parallel-processing, ipc, named-pipes, multiprocess

Gist of the program: The server creates n client processes. On the client user enters a character string that is sent to the server. On server the string is processed as follows : the frequency is counted the occurrence of vowels and numbers in the entered string. Further, this information is sent to the client, which prints answer.

Remarks:

1. Client is disposable
2. Answer output from server should not exist, it exists for debugging only

Gist of the bug: To get instant processing on the server and instant return of the response from the server to the client, you need to work with clients in the order of their creation. But if we enter a line into all clients except the first, then we will not see any actions from the server side (it will not print anything). But as soon as you enter a line into the first client, information from all clients will be processed immediately, and the processing will proceed in the order of creation of clients (according to the debug output of the server).

Question: How to implement independence of each client from its creation queue?

SERVER:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <limits>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif


#define PIPE_TIMEOUT 5000
#define BUFSIZE 4096


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ***ROUTINE STAFF***

    cout << "Server is lauched\n"
        "It will be terminated when all clients exits\n";


    if (argc > 2 || (argc == 2 && argv[argc - 1] != "--help")) {
        cout << "Program should be lauched this way:\n"
            "name_of_program --help\n"
            "Note: --help is optional\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (argc == 2 && argv[argc - 1] == "--help") {
        cout << "The server creates n client processes. On the client user\n"
            "enters a character string that is sent to the server.On server\n"
            "the string is processed as follows : the frequency is counted\n"
            "the occurence of vowels and numbers in the entered string. Further,\n"
            "this information is sent to the client.\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of clients: ";
    if (!(cin >> n) || (n < 0))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // cleaning buffer



    // ***CREATING PROCESSES***

    cout << "Generating " << n << " clients...\n";
    // struct _STARTUPINFO: Specifies the window station, desktop, standard handles, and appearance of the main window for a process at creation time.
    STARTUPINFO* si_arr = new STARTUPINFO[n];
    // struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION: Contains information about a newly created process and its primary thread. It is used with the CreateProcess() (and other).
    PROCESS_INFORMATION* pi_arr = new PROCESS_INFORMATION[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // ZeroMemory macro: Fills a block of memory with zeros.
        /*
        void ZeroMemory(
        [in] PVOID  Destination,
        [in] SIZE_T Length
        );
        */
        ZeroMemory(&si_arr[i], sizeof(si_arr[i]));
        // DWORD STARTUPINFO.cb: The size of the structure, in bytes.
        si_arr[i].cb = sizeof(si_arr[i]);
        ZeroMemory(&pi_arr[i], sizeof(pi_arr[i]));

        if (!CreateProcess(
        
            TEXT("C:\\Users\\andrewshnitko\\source\\repos\\pipe_client\\Debug\\pipe_client.exe"),   // name of program (like in cmd)
            NULL,        // arguments for program (like in cmd after name of program)
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // dwCreationFlags - The new process gets a new console instead of inheriting the parent one 
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si_arr[i],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi_arr[i])           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "All processes (pipe clients) created\n";


    // ***CREATING PIPE INSTANCES***

    HANDLE* pipe_instances = new HANDLE[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pipe_instances[i] = CreateNamedPipe(
            TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\os_lab4_pipe"),            // pipe name 
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,      // read/write access 
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |      // message-type pipe 
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |  // message-read mode 
            PIPE_WAIT,               // blocking mode 
            n,               // number of instances 
            1024,   // output buffer size 
            1024,   // input buffer size 
            PIPE_TIMEOUT,            // client time-out 
            NULL);                   // default security attributes 

        if (pipe_instances[i] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("CreateNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "All pipe instances created\n";

    // ***CONNECTING PIPE INSTANCES***

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_instances[i], NULL))
        {
            printf("ConnectNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "All pipe instances connected to clients\n";

    // ***PROCESSING***

    char buf[1024];
    DWORD read_bytes;
    DWORD written_bytes;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (ReadFile(pipe_instances[i], buf, 1024, &read_bytes, NULL))
        {
            char* str = new char[read_bytes];
            strncpy(str, buf, read_bytes);
            //char answer[1024]; // ready c-str to WriteFile

            int total_amount = 0;

            int vowel_amount = 0;
            int digit_amount = 0;
            double vowel_frequency = 0.0;
            double digit_frequency = 0.0;


            char vowels[] = "aeiouy";
            char digits[] = "0123456789";


            total_amount = strlen(str);
            printf("Total: %i\n", total_amount);

            // vowel
            char* vowel_search;
            vowel_search = strpbrk(str, vowels); // check for first occurence of vovel in str
            while (vowel_search != NULL) { // while vovels not end up in str
                vowel_amount++;
                vowel_search = strpbrk(vowel_search + 1, vowels);
            }
        
            vowel_frequency = (double)vowel_amount / (double)total_amount * 100.0;
        

            // digit
            char* digit_search;
            digit_search = strpbrk(str, digits); // check for first occurence of digit in str
            while (digit_search != NULL) { // while digits not end up in str
                digit_amount++;
                digit_search = strpbrk(digit_search + 1, digits);
            }
        
            digit_frequency = (double)digit_amount / (double)total_amount * 100.0;
        
            string pre_str;
            pre_str = "Total: " + to_string(total_amount) + "\n"
                "Vowels: " + to_string(vowel_amount) + "\n"
                "Frequency: " + to_string(vowel_frequency) + "\n"
                "Digits: " + to_string(digit_amount) + "\n"
                "Frequency:" + to_string(digit_frequency) + "\n";
        

            cout << pre_str;

            const char* answer = pre_str.c_str();
   
            if (!WriteFile(pipe_instances[i], answer, 1024, &written_bytes, NULL)) {
                printf("WriteFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "Reading, processing and writting was successful\n";

    // ***CLOSING PIPE INSTANCES***

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(pipe_instances[i]);
    }

    // !? - WaitMultipleObjects()


    delete[] pipe_instances;

    cout << "All pipe instances closed\n";

    // ***CLOSING PROCESSES***
    // The code written below is needed in order for the server to shutdown not earlier than the clients

    HANDLE* ev_hndl_arr = new HANDLE[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ev_hndl_arr[i] = pi_arr[i].hProcess;
    }

    // Wait until EACH child process exits.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(n, ev_hndl_arr, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        CloseHandle(pi_arr[i].hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi_arr[i].hThread);
    }

    delete[] si_arr;
    delete[] pi_arr;
    delete[] ev_hndl_arr;

    cout << "All processes (pipe clients) closed\n";

    cout << "This is the end of server execution\n";
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // fgets()
#include <string.h> // strpbrk()

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Client is launched\n";

    HANDLE hndlNP = CreateFile(
        TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\os_lab4_pipe"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        NULL, // Prevents other processes from opening a file or device
        NULL, // cannot be inherited by any child processes
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        NULL, // no attributes
        NULL // no template
        );
    if (hndlNP == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "CreateFile error\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "Pipe connection established\n";

    char text[1024];


    printf("Enter string (max 1023 symbols): ");
    gets_s(text, 1024); // replacement \n for \0


    char answer[1024];
    DWORD read_bytes;
    DWORD written_bytes;

    if (WriteFile(hndlNP, text, 1024, &written_bytes, NULL)) {
   
        if (!ReadFile(hndlNP, answer, 1024, &read_bytes, NULL)) {
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            system("pause"); // TEMPORARY
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("WriteFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
        system("pause"); // TEMPORARY
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "Writting and reading was successful\n";

    cout << answer;

    // ***CLOSING PIPE CONNECTION***
    CloseHandle(hndlNP);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
Server is launched
It will be terminated when all clients exits
Enter number of clients: 2
Generating 2 clients...
All processes (pipe clients) created
All pipe instances created
All pipe instances connected to clients
***BREAKPOINT 1: no answer from server, no debug output in server side (waiting state)***
(waiting)
***BREAKPOINT 2: immediate response from server and debug output from server(firstly about
first client(wrote for the second time), and then about second client(wrote for the first 
time)). All clients get answer from server***
Total: 16
Total: 16
Vowels: 4
Frequency: 25.000000
Digits: 8
Frequency:50.000000
Total: 11
Total: 11
Vowels: 2
Frequency: 18.181818
Digits: 5
Frequency:45.454545
Reading, processing and writting was successful
All pipe instances closed
(waiting for closure of clients(press any key...))
(termination)
```

Client (2nd): // First input into the second client

```
Client is launched
Pipe connection established
Enter string (max 1023 symbols): 12345qwerty
***BREAKPOINT 1: no answer from server, no debug output in server side (waiting state)***
(waiting)
***BREAKPOINT 2: immediate response from server and debug output from server(firstly about
first client(wrote for the second time), and then about second client(wrote for the first 
time)). All clients get answer from server***
Writting and reading was successful
Total: 11
Vowels: 2
Frequency: 18.181818
Digits: 5
Frequency:45.454545
Press any key to continue . . .
(press)
(termination)
```

Client (1st):

```
Client is launched
Pipe connection established
Enter string (max 1023 symbols): qwiouryq18927468
***BREAKPOINT 2: immediate response from server and debug output from server(firstly about 
first client(wrote for the second time), and then about second client(wrote for the first 
time)). All clients get answer from server***
Writting and reading was successful
Total: 16
Vowels: 4
Frequency: 25.000000
Digits: 8
Frequency:50.000000
Press any key to continue . . .
(press)
(termination)
```

Note: Client (1st) firstly created, then Client (2nd) created

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be minimal. Processing of the input doesn't appear to be part of the issue, just remove it.

Comment: when you do `if (ReadFile(pipe_instances[i], buf, 1024, &read_bytes, NULL))` in loop for every client.. already can say that all design is wrong. every connection must be handled independed

Comment: @RbMm, there is absolutely no way to change only a part of the code? Have to rewrite everything?

Comment: i sure that need rewrite everything. but this is my opinion only.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect different pipelines through multiple threads, you can refer to the following code:

Server.cpp

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <limits>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif


#define PIPE_TIMEOUT 5000
#define BUFSIZE 4096
HANDLE* pipe_instances = NULL;
int n = 0;


int f(int i)
{
    char buf[1024];
    DWORD read_bytes;
    DWORD written_bytes;
    if (ReadFile(pipe_instances[i], buf, 1024, &read_bytes, NULL))
    {
        char* str = new char[read_bytes];
        strncpy(str, buf, read_bytes);
        //char answer[1024]; // ready c-str to WriteFile

        int total_amount = 0;

        int vowel_amount = 0;
        int digit_amount = 0;
        double vowel_frequency = 0.0;
        double digit_frequency = 0.0;


        char vowels[] = "aeiouy";
        char digits[] = "0123456789";


        total_amount = strlen(str);
        printf("Total: %i\n", total_amount);

        // vowel
        char* vowel_search;
        vowel_search = strpbrk(str, vowels); // check for first occurence of vovel in str
        while (vowel_search != NULL) { // while vovels not end up in str
            vowel_amount++;
            vowel_search = strpbrk(vowel_search + 1, vowels);
        }

        vowel_frequency = (double)vowel_amount / (double)total_amount * 100.0;


        // digit
        char* digit_search;
        digit_search = strpbrk(str, digits); // check for first occurence of digit in str
        while (digit_search != NULL) { // while digits not end up in str
            digit_amount++;
            digit_search = strpbrk(digit_search + 1, digits);
        }

        digit_frequency = (double)digit_amount / (double)total_amount * 100.0;

        string pre_str;
        pre_str = "Total: " + to_string(total_amount) + "\n"
            "Vowels: " + to_string(vowel_amount) + "\n"
            "Frequency: " + to_string(vowel_frequency) + "\n"
            "Digits: " + to_string(digit_amount) + "\n"
            "Frequency:" + to_string(digit_frequency) + "\n";


        cout << pre_str;

        const char* answer = pre_str.c_str();

        if (!WriteFile(pipe_instances[i], answer, 1024, &written_bytes, NULL)) {
            printf("WriteFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ***ROUTINE STAFF***

    cout << "Server is lauched\n"
        "It will be terminated when all clients exits\n";


    //if (argc > 2 || (argc == 2 && argv[argc - 1] != "--help")) {
    //    cout << "Program should be lauched this way:\n"
    //        "name_of_program --help\n"
    //        "Note: --help is optional\n";
    //    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    //}
    //if (argc == 2 && argv[argc - 1] == "--help") {
    //    cout << "The server creates n client processes. On the client user\n"
    //        "enters a character string that is sent to the server.On server\n"
    //        "the string is processed as follows : the frequency is counted\n"
    //        "the occurence of vowels and numbers in the entered string. Further,\n"
    //        "this information is sent to the client.\n";
    //    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    //}

    cout << "Enter number of clients: ";
    if (!(cin >> n) || (n < 0))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // cleaning buffer



    // ***CREATING PROCESSES***

    cout << "Generating " << n << " clients...\n";
    // struct _STARTUPINFO: Specifies the window station, desktop, standard handles, and appearance of the main window for a process at creation time.
    STARTUPINFO* si_arr = new STARTUPINFO[n];
    // struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION: Contains information about a newly created process and its primary thread. It is used with the CreateProcess() (and other).
    PROCESS_INFORMATION* pi_arr = new PROCESS_INFORMATION[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // ZeroMemory macro: Fills a block of memory with zeros.
        /*
        void ZeroMemory(
        [in] PVOID  Destination,
        [in] SIZE_T Length
        );
        */
        ZeroMemory(&si_arr[i], sizeof(si_arr[i]));
        // DWORD STARTUPINFO.cb: The size of the structure, in bytes.
        si_arr[i].cb = sizeof(si_arr[i]);
        ZeroMemory(&pi_arr[i], sizeof(pi_arr[i]));

        if (!CreateProcess(

            TEXT("D:\\VS_test_projects\\Project2\\Debug\\c.exe"),   // name of program (like in cmd)
            NULL,        // arguments for program (like in cmd after name of program)
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // dwCreationFlags - The new process gets a new console instead of inheriting the parent one 
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si_arr[i],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi_arr[i])           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }





    cout << "All processes (pipe clients) created\n";


    // ***CREATING PIPE INSTANCES***

    pipe_instances = new HANDLE[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pipe_instances[i] = CreateNamedPipe(
            TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\os_lab4_pipe"),            // pipe name 
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,      // read/write access 
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |      // message-type pipe 
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |  // message-read mode 
            PIPE_WAIT,               // blocking mode 
            n,               // number of instances 
            1024,   // output buffer size 
            1024,   // input buffer size 
            PIPE_TIMEOUT,            // client time-out 
            NULL);                   // default security attributes 

        if (pipe_instances[i] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("CreateNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "All pipe instances created\n";

    // ***CONNECTING PIPE INSTANCES***

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_instances[i], NULL))
        {
            printf("ConnectNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cout << "All pipe instances connected to clients\n";

    // ***PROCESSING***

    thread* t = new thread[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        t[i] = thread(f, i);
    }


    cout << "Reading, processing and writting was successful\n";

    // ***CLOSING PIPE INSTANCES***
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(pipe_instances[i]);
    }

    // !? - WaitMultipleObjects()


    delete[] pipe_instances;

    cout << "All pipe instances closed\n";

    // ***CLOSING PROCESSES***
    // The code written below is needed in order for the server to shutdown not earlier than the clients

    HANDLE* ev_hndl_arr = new HANDLE[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ev_hndl_arr[i] = pi_arr[i].hProcess;
    }

    // Wait until EACH child process exits.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(n, ev_hndl_arr, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        CloseHandle(pi_arr[i].hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi_arr[i].hThread);
    }

    delete[] si_arr;
    delete[] pi_arr;
    delete[] ev_hndl_arr;

    cout << "All processes (pipe clients) closed\n";

    cout << "This is the end of server execution\n";
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.